# Mysql left join or much simpler way?

Tags: mysql

I need to order data according to order index from other table. and order the data with the same 'id' according to entry date.

i cant figure it out how to join data and order using mysql command.

Table1

```
id name order
1  Ali   1
2  Cenk  3
3  Tan   2
```

Table 2

```
id  tid    m     date
 1  232   msj1    3
 2  434   msj2    2
 1  453   msj4    1
 3  455   msj5    2
 2  541   msj6    4
 1  234   msj7    2
 3  132   msj8    6
```

Needed query result

```
id  tid    m     date
 1  453   msj4    1
 1  234   msj7    2
 1  232   msj1    3
 3  455   msj5    2
 3  132   msj8    6
 2  434   msj2    2
 2  541   msj6    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select t2.id, t2.tid, t2.m, t2.date 
from t2 
left join t1 on t2.id=t1.id 
order by t1.order
```

This orders by the ordering field from table 1.

Comment: If you look at the example, ordering by t1.order, t2.date may fit the required data better. I would also use an `INNER JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN`.